# UserManager.CreateAsync not working but works from another code snippet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

i have a web api as follows. When i call this API it just errors out on UserManager.CreateAsync line. The same code works from the default /register method on MVC Web API.

```
[Route("settestaccounts")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SetTestAccounts(TestAccounts TestAccount)
    {
        if ((TestAccount.AccountCount == 0) || (TestAccount.AccountCount < 0) || (!TestAccount.SecretKey.Equals("test")))
        {
            return BadRequest("Please send valid data");
        }

        db = new Entities();
        List<string> outLogins = new List<string>();

        do
        {
            string testLogin = null; // string.Empty;
            do
            {
                string login = string.Format("user{0}@domain.net", GetRandomNumber(1, 10000));
                testLogin = (from p in db.AspNetUsers
                             where p.UserName.Equals(login)
                             select p.Id).FirstOrDefault();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(testLogin))
                {
                    outLogins.Add(login);
                }
            } while (testLogin != null);
        } while (outLogins.Count < TestAccount.AccountCount);

        foreach (string email in outLogins)
         {
            var newAccounts = new AccountController();
            var registerAccount = new Models.RegisterBindingModel()
            {
                Email = email,
                FirstName = "test",
                LastName = "test",
                Password = "Wadirere123",
                ConfirmPassword = "Wadirere123",
                ZipCode = Convert.ToString(94111),
                RoleName = "User"
            };

            string confkey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfirmEmailValidKey"];
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = registerAccount.Email, Email = registerAccount.Email, FirstName = registerAccount.FirstName, LastName = registerAccount.LastName, ZipCode = registerAccount.ZipCode, RegistrationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, registerAccount.Password);

            var c = result.Errors;

            //   var role = await newAccounts.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, registerAccount.RoleName);

            //ApplicationUser user = await newAccounts.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(email.Trim());
            //string code = await newAccounts.UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            //IdentityResult result = await newAccounts.UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user.Id, code);
            //newAccounts.UpdateDatabaseAndSendWelcomeNotification(user.Id, null, confkey, result);
        }

        return Ok(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new OutLogins() { Logins = outLogins }));
    }
```

I also using API monitoring and in that code it shows that there is internal server error 500 but does not state what the error is?

NOTE: I am calling this API(settestaccounts) from a Python client but the register API is also called from Python code and that executes fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can check error using Errors property and fix it.